# Url amigable con # en htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, rewriterule

Tengo rato buscando como conseguir una url amigable con un enlace tipo ID, y no encotré como, asi que consulto a los expertos.

Tengo algo como esto:

```
misitio.com/servicios.php#cortes
```

por busco que la url sea algo asi:

```
misitio.com/cortes
o
misitio.com/servicios/cortes
```

esperaba que algo tipo esto funcionara, y no he encontrado algo parecido.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^cortes$ servicios.php#cortes
```

Gracias de antemano por su ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Para que funcione necesitas usar la bandera [`[NE]`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_ne) (noescape)

> De forma predeterminada, los caracteres especiales, como `&` y `?`, por ejemplo, se convertirán a su equivalente en código hexadecimal. El uso de la bandera `[NE]` evita que eso suceda.
> [...] Omitir el `[NE]` hará que el `#` se convierta a su equivalente en código hexadecimal `%23`

#### Ejemplo:

```
RewriteRule ^/servicios/cortes /servicios.php#cortes [NE]
```